# $E(X)$, $Var(X) $, and $Mgf_x(t)$ of a continuous uniform random variable on $[a,b]$

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-writing

I am wondering if I have found the $Var(X), E(X), Mgf_x(t)$ for a continuous uniform random variable on [a,b] correctly. My solution is below, could someone check whether its correct and correct me if needs be. Thanks

[image: solution]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just two small remarks:

1. The value at $t=0$ of the moment-generating function is $1$. The expression that you obtained is valid when $t\ne0$.
2. We have that $a^ba^c=a^{b+c}$, not $a^{bc}$. Hence, there is a mistake in the last line $$\frac{e^{tb}-e^{ta}}{t(b-a)}\ne \frac{e^t(e^b-e^a)}{t(b-a)}.$$

Everything else is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looks a okay, except for the last step.   $e^{ta}-e^{tb}~\neq~ e^t (e^a-e^b)$

Leave the MGF as $\dfrac{e^{ta}-e^{tb}}{t(b-a)}$ when $t\neq 0$

---

Note: It equals something else when $t=0$, so you should evaluate that too.